# "countOut" -- while loop entries not from the list are not counted in augmented assignment Python 3.6

Tags: python, list, while-loop, for-in-loop, augmented-assignment

This simple program should count entries from the list and print how many there were as well
 as counting entries that are not from the list. But for some reason it counts all entries as countIn despite if they are from the list or not... Appreciate your suggestions!

```
   fruitsList = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Grape', 'Peach', 'Mango',
                      'Pear', 'Papaya', 'Plum', 'Grapefruit', 'Cantaloupe']
    countIn=0
    countOut=0

    while True:
        response=input('Enter a fruit name (enter X to exit): ')
        if response.upper() == 'X':
            break
        for response in fruitsList:
            if response in fruitsList:
               countIn += 1
               break
            else:
               countOut += 1
    print('The user entered' , countIn, ' items in the list')
    print('The user entered' , countOut, ' items not in the list')
```

Comment: How many attempts does the player have?

Comment: as many as wanted really.

Comment: It should look like this :

Enter a fruit (x to exit): apple
Enter a fruit (x to exit): grape
Enter a fruit (x to exit): fly
Enter a fruit (x to exit): x
The user entered 2 items in the list
The user entered 1 items not in the list

Comment: You don't even need to loop through the list, you can just have your `if response in fruitsList:` and that will do just fine. You are using the same variable `response` for your input and for your iterator.

Comment: @kstullich I wish I can skip that. Our prof specifically asked for while loop and use augmented assignment to count entries in and out of the list.
I am having a hardest time with Python. Never have such issues with Java :))

Comment: @Rish you would still be using augmented assignment if you took out the for loop.....take a look at the answer posted below it's what I would do.

Comment: @kstullich looks like it works now! I am so confused though why it wouldn't do so by the book...

Comment: @Rish I am guessing cause you used the same variable name (`response`) for your iterator and `input()`. But also you then don't compare the iterator to the input given. You would need to say `if response == fruitsList:`. Since you are iterating through the whole list.

Comment: @kstullich ah I see. I'm gonna try "if response==fruitList" as well.. see how it goes. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
#!user/bin/env python

fruitsList = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Grape', 'Peach', 'Mango',
                      'Pear', 'Papaya', 'Plum', 'Grapefruit', 'Cantaloupe']
countIn=0
countOut=0

while True:
    response=input('Enter a fruit name (enter X to exit): ')
    if response.upper() == 'X':
        break
    elif response.title() in fruitsList:
        countIn += 1
    else:
        countOut += 1
print('The user entered' , countIn, ' items in the list')
print('The user entered' , countOut, ' items not in the list')
```

There is no need for a for-loop.

EDIT: I also made it case-insensitive now by adding the title() function for the response string.

Comment: awwww magic! Thanks a bunch! 
It maybe a question over the top, but does anyone know why it didn't work before? This is how my prof  wrote it really and he is great... usually leaves some spaces for us to think through though...

Comment: With the for-loop you were walking through the fruit list and assigning the variable response, even though response was already assigned to the input.